# XML Deserialization Error in C# - InvalidOperationException: <element xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'> was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I call a customer's web service. And it is return a XMLElement.
I want to deserialize this result but I got an error:

> InvalidOperationException: `<element xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>` was not expected.

I try like below:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(result.OuterXml);
var query = root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(r => r.FirstAttribute != null && r.FirstAttribute.Value == "ZER_ENTEGRASYON");
XmlSerializer XML = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ZerDataList));

using (var reader = new StringReader(query.ToString()))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ZerDataList));
    var someTest = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as ZerDataList;
}
```

result.OuterXml:

```
<xs:element name="ZER_ENTEGRASYON" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="ZER_DAYSYIKTRANSIT">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SIPARIS_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="BOLUM_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="SORUMLU" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="SAP_SIPARIS_NO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

ZerDataList:

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ZER_ENTEGRASYON")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute("element",Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
public class ZerDataList 
{
    [XmlElement("ZER_DAYSYIKTRANSIT")]
    public ZerData[] ZerData { get; set; }
}
[Serializable()]
public class ZerData
{       
    [XmlElement("SIPARIS_ID")]
    public int SIPARIS_ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("BOLUM_ID")]
    public int BOLUM_ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("SORUMLU")]
    public string SORUMLU { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("SAP_SIPARIS_NO")]
    public string SAP_SIPARIS_NO { get; set; }
 }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute("element",Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
```

a namespace cannot be mapped as an element, because it is not an element. thus the error:

> InvalidOperationException: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'> was not expected.

you should use it like this:

```
   [XmlElement(
   Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
```

taken from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But XmlElement doesn't support classes

Comment: that's true, because an element cannot be at class level, only at property level and that is the root of your problem.

Comment: I edited this like but didn't work:     

  [Serializable()]    public class ZerDataRoot
    {
        [XmlElement("ZER_ENTEGRASYON", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
        public ZerDataList ZerDataList { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ZER_ENTEGRASYON", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public class ZerDataList 
    {
        [XmlElement("ZER_DAYSYIKTRANSIT")]
        public ZerData[] ZerData { get; set; }
    }